# Posts approval using CanCan and Devise [Help Needed]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

How can I make the posts pending and waiting for admin approval?

I am using CanCan for making roles. My roles is a separate model. Users has_many roles :through assignments

I need something to notify the admin when he opens the posts index that there is a pending posts.

I want something like this a side bar have 
Approved Posts (x) Pending Posts (x) Deleted Posts (x)
where x is a variable number refers to the number of posts

Comment: I've rewritten this and it may not be what you were intending. However, please try a little harder to write decent English. Failing to do so is fastest way to not get answered.

Comment: How do you want to notify the admin? Email, text, pigeon, push?

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter in your model

```
def self.pending
  where(status: 'pending')
end

def self.approved
  where(status: 'approved')
end
```

Then use:

```
Post.pending
```

You could refine the search params too if you don't want to select every variable in your model.

In your view, the following should do:

```
<%= Post.pending.size %>
```

Well, that will give you the count.

Or, because it's nice to move this into a controller. You could add this to your controllers action:

```
@pending = Post.pending.size
```

And then use the following in your view:

```
<%= @pending %>
```

== Edit ==

To automatically add pending to user posts and approve the admin posts, you could do something like this in your controller actions (update and save):

```
@post.pending = false if current_user.admin? 
@post.save
```

Or put it in an existing block where you don't need to call save on it to save db queries.

Obviously, that assumes pending is set to true by default in your db and there are otherways to do this.

Comment: first i have to add two attributes called `pending` and `approved` , right ?

Comment: can you explain it for me in steps until the `view` , i already have a working `articles model` just need to know what to do next, do you need to see my `model` and `controller` ?

Comment: and how to make the post , if a normal user should be pending and if he is an admin should be posted automatically

Comment: That's a little bit out of the scope of this question. I have however updated my question.